# Event afterSetExtremes is firing repeatedly with Highstock 1.3.0

Tags: highcharts

I just upgraded my app to use Highstock 1.3.0.

Prior to the upgrade, the xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes event fired only once, after the user stopped sliding or adjusting the x Axis range slider.

Now, the event fires repeatedly. Is this change in behavior intended? If so, is there a best practice way to throttle, or to know when the user activity has stopped?

p.s. "prior" ===> Highstock JS v1.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation (looked at the latest async load demo) I discovered an attribute that I can set in the options of a new Chart that seems to solve this problem:

```
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false
},
```